# How can we change color of a text programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

My code is

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1
{
    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height; 
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

    char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 18, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 2);

    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 10, 170, text, strlen(text));

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

How can we change the color of the text programmatically?
Answers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is just change the last instance of `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` to the RGB value you'd like. Right now it's white. Change the 255, 255, 255 part to the corresponding RGB value you'd like (0.0 - 1.0 range per color channel). ie. Red would be 1.0, 0.0, 0.0; Blue 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Yellow 1.0, 1.0, 0; Black 0.0, 0.0, 0.0; etc.... Good luck

Edit: range is 0.0-1.0 not 0-255

Comment: That's not the range of the arguments to the `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 2);
```

How can we change the color of the text programmatically?

That's one way, although you're doing it wrong. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetRGBFillColor); all four of those values are out of range, with three of them being *way* out of range.